# Accessing grouping variables from a group instance generated by groupby()

Tags: pandas, group-by

I'm wondering how to access the grouping variables from an individual instance of a group, rather than from the GroupBy object itself.

The docs use this example to show how the grouping vars and the group can be obtained from the GroupBy object iteratively:

```
In [43]: for name, group in df.groupby(['A', 'B']):
....:        print(name)
....:        print(group)
....: 
('bar', 'one')
    A    B         C         D
1  bar  one -0.042379 -0.089329
```

However, I am using apply() along with a custom function to compute some statistics for each group. The call to split, compute, and recombine into a data frame is then:

```
df.groupby(['A','B']).apply(myfunc).reset_index()
```

And myfunc has the signature:

```
def myfunc(g): #do some stuff with the group(=g), a DataFrame object
```

What I'd like to be able to do is get the values of columns A and B that identify this group g (e.g. 'bar', 'one'). Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Can't you just manually access the group components within `myfunc`, e.g. `g['A']`?

Comment: yes, but that returns a Series. in theory they should all be the same value, so I could just take the first element, but this is ugly and I was wondering if there was a better way. Also it would require manually going through the grouping columns to assemble the collection of values that uniquely identify this group. This is obviously much worse than simply being able to say g.gvars() and get back ('bar','one')...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use  `.name`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['bar','bar','bar','foo','foo','foo'],
                   'B':['one','one','one','one','one','one'],
                   'C':[7,8,9,3,4,6]})

print (df)

def myfunc(x):
    print (x.name)
    if (x.name == ('bar', 'one')):
        x.C +=10
    return x

print (df.groupby(['A','B']).apply(myfunc).reset_index())
   index    A    B   C
0      0  bar  one  17
1      1  bar  one  18
2      2  bar  one  19
3      3  foo  one   3
4      4  foo  one   4
5      5  foo  one   6
```

Comment: are you sure this works? I'm trying in pandas 0.17.1 and get `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'name'`...

Comment: Works for me on pandas 0.18.1.

Comment: I test it in pandas `0.18.1` and it works nice. Do you try my sample?

Comment: just upgraded to 0.18.1 and tested, `.name` is indeed the solution i was looking for. thanks!

Comment: as of `pandas.__version__ = '1.0.4'` the variables are directly accessible such as x['A'] or x['B']